# check if an item starts with a symbol in a tuple Python

Tags: python-3.x, text-processing

```
a = {
    'a' : [
        ('a', '"Folks marched &amp; protested for our right to vote." --@FLOTUS\n', 1477610322, 'TweetDeck', 545, 226),
        ('a', '"We urge voters to dump Trump" --@DenverPost', 1476205194, 'TweetDeck', 7165, 2225)
        ],
    'b:' : [
        ('b:', 'Join me in #Atlanta November 2. Details-  #YouIn? #JohnsonWeld\n', 1478034098, 'Hootsuite', 108, 51)
        ]
    }

for key, value in a.items():
    for item in value:
        #extract string beginning with #'s with the user (the users are a and b)
```

I'm trying to extract hashtags with the user indicated with it, from the tuple. I only know the method startswith but you cannot use it for tuples.

Comment: What is `string`? Looks like you need to extract the tags from arbitrary positions in a string - the `re` module would probably be the best bet, e.g. `re.findall(r'#\w*', item[1])`

Comment: i cant import anything

Comment: You mean you aren't allowed to do "import re"?

Comment: You should be able to iterate through your data structure easily enough, extracting the strings which appear as the second item in the tuples in the lists which are the values of the dictionary. Once you grab such a string you can split it and iterate through it word by word, using `startswith` on those words.

Comment: @bli -- such a restriction is a clear indication that this is homework.

Comment: @bli import re or any other module other than doctest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split a string using the `split` method, which by default splits on whitespaces:

```
s = 'Join me in #Atlanta November 2. Details-  #YouIn? #JohnsonWeld\n'
s.split() 
# ['Join', 'me', 'in', '#Atlanta', 'November', '2.', 'Details-', '#YouIn?', '#JohnsonWeld']
```

You can then use `startswith` on each resulting element to check if it is a hashtag, in a list comprehension:

```
[tag for tag in s.split() if tag.startswith("#")]
# ['#Atlanta', '#YouIn?', '#JohnsonWeld']
```

You can encapsulate this in a function for more readable code:

```
def get_hashtags_from_string(s):
    return [tag for tag in s.split() if tag.startswith("#")]
```

Comment: but i have  a tuple tho

Comment: You can apply the function to the element of the tuple you want. If you expect hashtags to be present in the second element: `get_hashtags_from_string(item[1])` (remembering that python indexing is zero-based).

Comment: If you want to get rid of elements like `'b', []`, you can probably test if the list of hashtags is empty before deciding to append it to your `author` list.

Comment: what would i have to do if i only want to return a unique hashtag(hashtags that are only used by specific candidates).

Comment: It is probably better to ask a specific separate question for this. Have a look at the available data structures and what one can do with them: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html This could give you some ideas.